# Displaying Graph to the user

Tags: django, web-development-server, python-3.7

I want to show a graph(using matplotlib) to the user. In which Django diretory should I place my code? I tried placing the code in personal directory and defined the attribute in views.py, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new directory, say `my_matplotlib`, in the root of your aplication, add an `__init__.py` file so it can be called as a module. Add there your files with the code you want.

```
root/
    my_matplotlib/
        __init__.py
        my_matplotlib.py
    app/
        views.py
```

**my_matplotlib.py**

```
def my_func():
    foo = 'bar'
    return foo
```

Then you can call it as module, and the methods and classes it may contain throughout the application.

Example

**app/views.py**

```
from my_matplotlib.my_matplotlib import my_func
```